# accessing Isolated Storage data in a different page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I created an `IsolatedStorageSettings` to store data of the Player
and i created that inside the **SetProfile.xaml** page

So in the MainPage.xaml , there is a TextBlock holding a text "Hello "

I want to do something like this :

`TextBlock1.Text = "Hello " +(THE NAME OF THE PLAYER);`

and that's where i need to access the **Isolated Storage**
how i can do that ?

**SetProfile.xaml**

```
 IsolatedStorageSettings Profile = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

private void create_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
                Player player = new Player(); // Player is a class 
                player.FirstName = FirstName.Text;
                player.LastName = LastName.Text;
                player.Age = Convert.ToInt32(Age.Text);
                player.Rank = 1;
                player.RankDescreption = "Beginner";

                if (Profile.Contains("profile"))
                {
                    Profile.Remove("profile");
                    Profile.Add("profile", player);
                    Profile.Save();
                }

                else
                {
                    Profile.Add("profile", player);
                    Profile.Save();
                }

                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }


  private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("profile"))
               NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HelloName.Text = "Hello " + (WHAT I NEED) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could read setting value like this:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("profile"))
       {
         Player player =(Player)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["profile"];         
        HelloName.Text ="Hello"+ player.FirstName;
       }      
    }
```

[click in this doc to know more about settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: use this it will definetly helpfull for you

Comment: But i want to access a specefic field which it's FirstName